# What is the difference between xavier_initializer and xavier_initializer_conv2d?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I noticed that TensorFlow 1.0 contains two Xavier initalization helpers in contrib,

- [tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer) and
- [tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/xavier_initializer)

Both link to the same documentation page and have the same signature:

```
tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=True, seed=None, dtype=tf.float32)
tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(uniform=True, seed=None, dtype=tf.float32)
```

however the difference between them is not explained at all. I can guess by the name that the `_conv2d` version should be used for 2D convolutional layers, but would it have a noticeable impact if one were to use the regular version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is actually no difference. Because both the functions implement the weight initialization from:

> Xavier Glorot and Yoshua Bengio (2010): [Understanding the difficulty of training deep feedforward neural networks.](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf?hc_location=ufi) International conference on artificial intelligence and statistics.

Both the initializer is designed to keep the scale of the gradients roughly the same in all layers. In uniform distribution this ends up being the range: `x = sqrt(6. / (in + out)); [-x, x]` and for normal distribution a standard deviation of `sqrt(3. / (in + out))` is used.

Comment: To expand on that for future readers: Looking at the code, it turns out that `xavier_initializer_conv2d` isn't even a separate function, only an alias for `xavier_initializer`.

Comment: The exact line is here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/initializers.py#L59